# Does the Ackermann function count something?

Tags: co.combinatorics, ct.category-theory

Let $\mathrm{FinSet}$ be the category of finite sets.

A *finite set structure* is a faithful functor $F\colon C\to \mathrm{FinSet}$ such that, for any $n\geq 1$, there are only finitely many isomorphism classes of objects $F$ maps to $\{1, \dots, n\}$.

> **Question.** Is there a natural finite set structure realizing the Ackermann function (or some other computable function growing faster
> than any primitive recursive function)?

Comment: The Ackermann function $A(m,n)$ takes two inputs; apart from this, if I understand well, you're asking about the existence of a species of structure whose associated exponential series (in the variables X,Y) is $\sum \frac{A(m,n)}{n!m!}X^nY^m$. First of all, is this series convergent?

Comment: @fosco I had in mind $f(n)=A(n, n)$

Comment: oh, fair enough; well, is the series $\sum \frac{f(n)}{n!}X^n$ convergent in at least a disk $B(0,\epsilon[$?

Comment: @fosco : why is the convergence of the series relevant to the question ?

Comment: @fosco, surely [not](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/392387/does-the-ackermann-function-count-something#comment1001256_392387); $f(n) \ge (n!)^2$ eventually.

Comment: hi @SimonHenry ! To a combinatorial species you can associate various formal power series, and especially from the exponential series you can understand a lot about the species itself --although not everything. Ad yes, that series it's not convergent, so there is no associated function you can study. This makes the problem elusive, even provided you find a meaning for what kind of structure $A(n,n)$ is counting.

Comment: I'm not sure how to understand this question. For any function $f:\mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ I can chose a sequence of sets $P_n$ such that $\# P_n = f(n)$ and take $C$ to be a naively defined category with an object for each $i \in P_n$ mapping to a set with $n$ elements... so any functions can be obtained this way.

Comment: @SimonHenry yes you can associate some category but I wondered if there was a natural (in the vague sense of the word) choice. Maybe a structure arising independently elsewhere in mathematics.

Comment: @fosco : yes but,I am not aware of anything that forces the exponential generating function of combinatorial species to converge, so why would the convergence brings anything to the question ? But maybe you have in mind some result proving the convergence for some class of "nice" species ?

Comment: @SimonHenry even though the question isn't phrased in this way, I suspect it is asking about a species of structure with the Ackermann function as generating species. I have no idea what the sequence $a_n=A(n,n)$ could be counting, though, and throwing the [very few terms](https://oeis.org/A046859) of the sequence that can be computed at OEIS doesn't seem a viable choice: is there a combinatorial interpretation for those numbers?

Comment: Not sure why this (good) question has a category theory tag, but there is a kind of "categorical number theory / combinatorics" that was studied by Steve Schanuel. I don't know any more than that.

Comment: There is a whole "school" of enumerative combinatorics done using Joyal's species! Relevant names are Joyal himself, [Labelle](https://tinyurl.com/2jmmmwwa), [Leroux, Viennot](https://tinyurl.com/3j24pf3t), [Mendez](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82208163.pdf), [Rajan](https://tinyurl.com/uchj2prv)...

Comment: Interesting question. Maybe some nested set-partition-like structures? A stupid answer would be to take a deterministic rewrite system that takes $A\left(n,m\right)$ steps to terminate (I think there should be one), and just say "the intermediate states of this rewrite system".

Comment: The inverse Ackermann function appears in some algorithms, e.g. using a "soft heap" you can find the minimum spanning tree in time $O(m\alpha(m, n))$. A decade ago I probably knew why and whether something was being counted.

Comment: So, I do not know  what the Ackermann function counts, but the TREE function does count something explicit and combinatorial, and the Ackermann function is tiny in comparison with TREE. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/93828/how-large-is-tree3